# automatically refresh page when someone makes changes

Tags: javascript, php, comet

I have a page where i have some text that I take from the database.
While that page is open and someone else changes the text in the database, I wan't to make it so that my page is immediatly refreshed when the data changes.

I have googled around and found some stuff about using comet, but I don't understand anything about it.

Is there a more simple way to solve my problem? and if not, does anyone know a simple tutorial for comet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods that come to my mind. The first in the category 'push-messages'. Not a lot of experience with that, so im going to continue to option 2:

Add a last-edit timestamp in the same table/row as `text` is. When someone updates the text, update the timestamp.

When an user loads a page, also send the last-edit timestamp in a javascript variable. Then make a super-lightweight AJAXcall to a verify-file, along the lines of this:

```
$query = "SELECT text,last_edit FROM someTable WHERE lastedit>".$_GET['timestampFromJS']." LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if( $result->num_rows===0 ){
    echo 0; // something small for JS
}
else{
    $fetch = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo $fetch['text'];
}
```

In the success handler of your javascript code, check if the value is not equal to `0`, if it's not `0`, use the result to update the page.

There might be other solutions, or you might prefer JSON (I know I do :P), but you'll get the draft of the idea :)